# Adding colors to graphic objects made with the new function AnglePath

Tags: graphics, functions

The MMA 10.2 help gives many examples of `AnglePath` lines of code but all of them are of the same color and I am quite at a loss to devise a method to add colors whenever I practise with this function.
My difficulty is that you can't decide of the color in the parameters of `Anglepath`. If for example you want to draw a line with many segments, each segment having a different color, you have to repeat the sequence (color, graphic primitive, line) for each each segment and I'm not experienced enough to tackle this correctly.

Let's take this example:

```
g1 = Graphics@{NestList[
 Rotate[#, Pi/5, {0, 0}] &, {RandomColor[], 
 Line[AnglePath[{{-0.7, -0.7}, (-Pi/6)}, {{2, (7 \[Pi])/
     8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}, {2, (7 \[Pi])/8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}}]]}, 9]}
```

How can I get in the above graphics first a different random color for each leaf and then for each leaf a different color for each segment of line?

And in this example with a different graphic primitive `Polygon` how can I get for each leaf a different color ?

```
g2 = Graphics@{NestList[
Rotate[#, Pi/5, {0, 0}] &, {RandomColor[], 
Polygon[AnglePath[{{0, 0}, (-Pi/6)}, {{2, (7 \[Pi])/
     8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}, {2, (7 \[Pi])/8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}}]]}, 9]}
```

Is the answer specific to `Polygon` or independant of the graphic primitive? (I'm thinking of closed `BSplineCurves` graphics obtained with `AnglePath`)

Below I combined  both graphics obtained in my question.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your examples you choose one color to begin with and then you pass that color onwards to each of the following leaves through recursion. Just like you have to apply `Rotate` in each step to change the angle, you also have to apply an operator that changes the color. For example:

```
next[{_, leaf_}] := {RandomColor[], Rotate[leaf, Pi/5, {0, 0}]}

g1 = Graphics@{
   NestList[
    next, {
     RandomColor[],
     Line[AnglePath[
       {{-0.7, -0.7}, (-Pi/6)},
       {{2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/8}, {2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/8}}
       ]]}, 9]
   }
```

Or you could skip the recursion altogether, it really just makes it more complicated since your problem doesn't really call for a recursive solution.

```
leaf[angle_, color_] := {color, Rotate[Line@AnglePath[
     {{-0.7, -0.7}, -Pi/6},
     {{2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/8}, {2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/8}}
     ], angle, {0, 0}]}

Graphics@Table[leaf[angle, RandomColor[]], {angle, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}]
```

Adapting these solutions to the second example is left as an exercise, as those solutions proceed in the same way.

To give different segments different colors you should create one line for each segment. Like this:

```
segments = Partition[AnglePath[{{1.2, 90. °}, {2.1, 130. °}, {0.7, -85. °}}], 2, 1];
colors = {RandomColor[], RandomColor[], RandomColor[]};

Graphics@MapThread[{#, Line[#2]} &, {colors, segments}]
```

This approach can be applied to your example like this:

```
leaf[angle_, colors_] := Thread[{
   colors,
   Rotate[Line[#], angle, {0, 0}] & /@ Partition[AnglePath[
      {{-0.7, -0.7}, -Pi/6},
      {{2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/8}, {2, (7 π)/8}, {2, π/
         8}}
      ], 2, 1]}]

Graphics@Table[leaf[angle, Table[RandomColor[], {4}]], {angle, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

Similar comments on recursion. The expression you create looks like this:

```
TreeForm[orig, VertexLabeling -> None]
```

[image]

Building it, e.g., like this gives you a flat structure:

```
new = Table[
  Rotate[
    Line[AnglePath[{{-0.7, -0.7}, (-Pi/6)}, {{2, (7 \[Pi])/8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}, {2, (7 \[Pi])/8}, {2, \[Pi]/8}}]],
    i*Pi/5, {0, 0}],
  {i, 10}];
```

[image]

Such structures are easy to operate on with replacement rules:

```
new /. l_Line :> ReplaceList[l, 
  Line[{___, pt1_, pt2_, ___}] :> {RandomColor[], Line[{pt1, pt2}]}] // Graphics
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answers received made me cogitate a lot these last two days and I came up with a solution based on `Riffle`:

All the graphics directives are stored in a table, each entry in that table corresponding to a path of the figure drawn . These paths are in a table supplied to the unique built-in drawing the figure (ie `Line`, `Polygon`....) here `BezierCurve`.
The `Riffle` function is of the form `Riffle[list,x,n]` where `n` is here the number (+1) of graphics directives.

```
 Graphics@{NestList[Rotate[#, Pi/6, {1, -3}] &, 
  Riffle[Flatten[Table[{Hue[1/n], Thickness[0.01]}, {n, 1, 20, 2}]], 
  BezierCurve[#, SplineDegree -> 4, SplineClosed -> True] & /@ 
  Table[AnglePath[{Cos[0 + k], 
    Sin[0 + k]}, {{15, 2 Pi/3}, {20, 2 Pi/3}, {1, 2 Pi/3}}], {k, 
    0, 2, 0.2}], 3 ], 12]};
```

It's straightforward to change to another figure or surface.
MMA has a lot of flexibility for a given task and no doubt many  ways can be found to add colors to `AnglePath` based figures.
[image]